# ejb-client Maven dependencies in Eclipse

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, wildfly, m2e, maven-ear-plugin

I use a dependency with `ejb-client` type in a Maven project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <type>ejb-client</type>
</dependency>
```

It works properly when I build the project with Maven: it includes a version of the dependency that has remote EJB interfaces only (no implementations).

However, when I export the project to Eclipse Luna, and deploy it from Eclipse to jBoss/WildFly, Eclipse copies the full version of the dependency as if I used `<type>ejb</type>`.

Eclipse also gives me a warning:

> Dependency to project foo with type ejb-client is not fully
>   supported. Classpath and/or deployment issues might arise. Try
>   Maven->Disable Workspace Resolution...

Is there a way to make `ejb-client` dependencies to work in Eclipse? Or is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2):

In the past I've found that `ejb-client` jars are not a very good idea. They share the same dependencies as the full ejb-jar and you normally don't want that. You will also find that IDE support for these is a little weak.

You're far better off hand building your remote EJB API as a separate `jar` artefact and including it where needed.

Comment: I considered this approach, but I do not want to create an additional API project.